# How to make square wave from sine wave in java?

Tags: java, math

```
int[]x = new int[1000];
int[]y = new int[1000];
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
 x[i] = i+50;
 y[i] = 350+(int)(text1*Math.sin(i*text2));

}

g.setColor( Color.black);

Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

g2.setStroke(new Basic Stroke(text));
g2.drawPolyline(x,y,1000);
super.paint(g);panel 2. paint Components(g);
```

This is the code for sine wave, what can i do to make this wave in to a square wave? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn a sine wave in to a square wave, take the [`signum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum-double-) of the `sin`.

```
double    sinPoint = Math.sin( i * text2 );
double squarePoint = Math.signum( sinPoint );
y[i] = 350 + (int)( text1 * squarePoint );
```

This is mentioned in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave#Other_definitions).

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be to take a time period to 'T'

Then calculate Run a loop for i variable then do i%T < T/2 then value in y axis is one otherwise it will be -1